# How to display activity indicator in the middle of the page of a WKWebView using swift?

Tags: swift, wkwebview, activity-indicator

I'm using a WKWebView in an IOS application and I've manage to make the activity indicator appear on the upper left corner of the status bar. How can I display it in the middle of the screen?

Here is the following code that I'm using :

```
@IBOutlet var containerView : UIView! = nil

var webView: WKWebView?

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    self.webView = WKWebView()
    self.view = self.webView!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string:"https://www.example_link.com/")
    let req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
    self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    webView!.navigationDelegate = self

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        }


func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

}
```

Comment: Use the `UIActivityIndicatorView` from the storyboard, put it at the middle with some constraints (center vertically/horizontally). Then rely it to your `UIViewController` and then you can show / hide it when you load a request in your webView.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using UIActivityIndicatorView with UIWebView in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401733/using-uiactivityindicatorview-with-uiwebview-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

No you cant. NetworkActivityIndicator is part of status bar and its position cant be changed. What you can do is to create a `UIActivityIndicatorView` and place it wherever you want in the same way as how you place other views.

Comment: I've tried to do it with the UIActivityIndicatorView but it's not working.